# Can't locate html location of form

Tags: html, forms, joomla, joomla2.5

I need to find where the form is nestled within the code so I can remove a field. 
I found the *if statements* that do the function, but I can't locate where the form is pulled from.  THe component I use to process payments doesn't have any fields to adjust, so I have to go to the code.

https://www.chosenpeople.com/main/donate/index.php?option=com_dtdonate&controller=authorizenet&task=authorizenet&Itemid=360

This is the function that pulls the form. . .

```
 if($row->paymentmethod =='authorize.net' && $paymentfrequecy!="once" && $paymentfrequecy!=""){



            if(isset($_POST['donations']) && isset($_POST['startdate'])){



                $adminmsg.="<tr><td>".JText::_( 'DT_START_DATE').":</td><td> ".$_POST['startdate']."</td></tr>";



                $adminmsg.="<tr><td>".JText::_( 'DT_NUMBER_DONATIONS').":</td><td> ".$_POST['donations']."</td></tr>";
```

Comment: Field for what? Which view of the component? Have you tried checking the components folder? You most likely won't get a reply on here as this is for a commercial extension

Comment: I'm sorry, why would you be looking for main/donation/index? that would not be something normally found in Joomla.  You should probably read basic Joomla documentation before trying to modify files you don't understand.  Most likely it's going to be a simple override but it's hard to tell if you don't post the content of the template.

Comment: I worded my issue different, please read above

Comment: Also, if you go to the link I put, you will see in the source code that there is actual html code that creates the Form. I can't locate where that is. I used to be able to find location of code 1.2.3

Comment: I get the feeling this component was build for Joomla 1.5 and mildly modified for Joomla 2.5+ ... As mentioned before, this is a commercial extension, so how are people supposed to view the source of it to help you? Have you checked the view file (assuming this component is mvc based) ?

Comment: I'd really use something that is correctly coded unless you have a lot of data in there.   I doubt you can modify the data supplied to authorize.net.

Answer (score 0):

Controllers will trigger execution of other views, models etc.

You controller is named something like

```
/components/com_dtdonate/controllers/authorizenet.php
```

You need to look at its code (the `authorizenet()` function) to know what it's doing.

It should be loading the form either from

```
/components/com_dtdonate/models/forms/authorizenet.xml
```

or something similar, or building it in code in a view (the view name should be apparent in the controller function you just looked at) i.e.

```
/components/com_dtdonate/views/someviewname/tmpl/default.php
```